# Why @Constraints annotation are not working on my tests?

Tags: java, playframework, annotations, playframework-2.0, ebean

I've created this `User` class:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Email
    public String email;

    @Constraints.MinLength(3)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(255)
    public String firstName;

    @Constraints.MinLength(3)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(255)
    public String lastName;

    @Constraints.MinLength(3)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(255)
    public String username;

    @Constraints.MinLength(16)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(255)
    public String password;

    public static Finder<String, User> finder = new Finder<>(User.class);

    public static User create(User user){
        user.password = BCrypt.hashpw(user.password, BCrypt.gensalt(12));
        user.save();
        return user;
        }
     ...
}
```

And I noticed that I can save an *empty* `User`. Which means, with no `email`, nothing, this User will be persisted on my database.

```
    @Test
    public void createEmptyUser(){
        User user = new User();
        user.email="";
        user.save();

        assertTrue(user.email.isEmpty());
        assertNotNull(User.finder.byId(user.email));
        assertEquals(true, User.findByEmail(user.email).isPresent());
    }
```

Why is my test passing ?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see here https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java-forms/src/main/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.java the `isValid` method of the `EmailValidator` class returns true if its agrument is an empty string:

```
public static class EmailValidator extends Validator<String> implements ConstraintValidator<Email, String> {

        public boolean isValid(String object) {

            if(object == null || object.length() == 0) {
                return true;
            }

            return regex.matcher(object).matches();
        }
}
```

Consider adding `@Constraints.Required`and `@Formats.NonEmpty` to this validation. Also, you can see that the `MinLength` and `MaxLength` validators behave in the same way.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but no luck. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Exactly! The other fields are expecting a minimum value at least, and I don't understand why is behaving like this.

Comment: From my point of view, returning always `true` in the `MinLength` validator if the agrument has zero length is not correct. As well as an empty email is not a correct email. I can understand returning `true` if the argument is `null`; but not if it is empty string. So, possible bug of the Play Framework, may be :)